# How to use Lwt_pool

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I want to have a pool of Redis database connections with a max number of connections. It looks like [`Lwt_pool`](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.4.3/api/Lwt_pool) is the solution I am looking for, but I don't quite grasp how it should work. For example, some questions I have:

- The docs talk about `Lwt_pool` being great to reuse open connections, but how does the pool know what connections are available for reuse? As far as I see, there is no particular way to signal that and the API only provides the `use` method.
- Is there any resource better than the `Lwt` docs to learn how it works? I can't easily find code examples or many resources available about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The function you pass to `use` returns a thread. When the thread finishes, the connection is released back to the pool.
- The source code is fairly easy to read. In this case:

  ```
  let use p f =
    acquire p >>= fun c ->
    Lwt.catch
      (fun () ->
         let t = f c in
         t >>= fun _ ->
         release p c;
         t)
      (fun e ->
         checked_release p c;
         Lwt.fail e)
  ```

Comment: Thanks, your first comment was what made it click.